# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ where $b=2^{1/3}+\zeta_3$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, \zeta_3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Show that $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ where $b=2^{1/3}+\zeta_3$ and $\zeta_3$ is a third root of unity is equal to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, \zeta_3)$?

I am not sure how to get $2^{1/3}$ and $\zeta_3$ from $b$...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $K/F$ is algebraic, then the minimal polynomial of any $\alpha \in K$ is given by $\displaystyle m_{\alpha}(x) = \prod (x - \alpha_i)$, where $\{a_i\}$ is the orbit of $\alpha$ under the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$.

In this case, we have $\operatorname{Gal}( \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)/ \mathbb{Q}) \cong S_3$, with a basis given by $\sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto \omega \sqrt[2]{3}$ and $i \mapsto -i$ (where $\omega$ represents a primitive third root of unity).  Let's look at the orbit of $\sqrt[3]{2} + \omega$; it contains:

- $\sqrt[3]{2} + \omega$
- $\omega \sqrt[3]{2}+ \omega$
- $\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2} + \omega$
- $\sqrt[3]{2}  + \omega^2$
- $ \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2} + \omega^2$
- $\omega \sqrt[3]{2} + \omega^2$

Since there are six elements in the orbit, it must be the case that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2} + \omega$ is $6 \implies [E: \mathbb{Q}] = 6$.  Since we also have $E \subseteq \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$ and $[ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[3]{2}, \omega) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$, it follows that the two fields are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the splitting field $K$  of $x^3-2$, that is the field having all the three cubic roots of 2. It is generated by $2^{1/3}, \zeta 2^{1/3}, \zeta^22^{1/3}$. Clearly $K$  contains $\zeta$ (ratio of two of the numbers above). 
Actually $K$ is generated by $\zeta$ and $2^{1/3}$ and so is of degree 6 over the rationals.

So $K$ contains the field $\mathbf Q[b]$ that is in your question.

We can deduce $\mathbf Q[b]=K$ once we show  that its degree is neither 3 nor 2.  That is not difficult. Then there must exist expressions in terms of $b$ for $\zeta$ and $2^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[3]{2})$ has degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so one could show that the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ has degree $6$, perhaps by computing the minimal polynomial of $b$. With some work (I used Wolfram Alpha for this computation), one can compute successive powers of $b$ to show that $b$ is a root of $p(x) = x^{6} + 3x^{5} + 6x^{4} + 3x^{3} + 9x + 9$, and $p(x)$ is in fact the minimal polynomial of $b$. However, I don't know of an easy way to show this; the computation is laborious, and Eisenstein doesn't work on $p(x)$ or any nearby translates I checked.

Appyling Galois theory yields a more elegant approach. Note that $K := \mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[3]{2})$ is the splitting field of $x^{3} - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and hence is a Galois extension. The Galois group $G$ of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ has order $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 6$, and it is not hard to see that $G$ is generated by the noncommuting automorphisms $\sigma, \tau$, where $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are defined on generators by 
$$\sigma(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \zeta\sqrt[3]{2}, \sigma(\zeta) = \zeta; \tau(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \sqrt[3]{2}, \tau(\zeta) = \zeta^{2}$$
whence $G \cong S_{3}$. How does this relate to the degree of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

The degree of $b$ is given by the size of the Galois orbit of $b$, i.e. by the size of the set $S_{b} := \{\sigma(b) \mid \sigma \in G\}$, and in fact, the minimal polynomial $m_{b}(x)$ of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ factors as $\prod_{\beta \in S_{b}} (x-\beta)$ over $K$. The galois orbits of $b$ are given by $\zeta^{i} + \zeta^{j}\sqrt[3]{2}$, where $i = 1, 2, j = 0, 1, 2$, whence we can see that $|S_{b}| = 6$. Hence, the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ and $K$ must be equal, as desired.